# Cloud-free way to move everything (data-transfer) from one device to another?

Tags: data-transfer

I would like to move everything from one device to another, including data from contacts, applications etc.

I would like to do this in cloud-free way, i.e. without copying everything to Google or any other third party provider.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's the device you're using. One way you could do is  through the official suite application provided by the device manufacturer, such as KIES for Samsung... etc.

Comment: Also depends on how complete you want. There are separate solutions for contacts, SMS, app data backup, etc., combine them to your heart's desire.

Comment: @AzkerM never seen KIES working for many years, so didn't try it

Comment: With the conflicting ideas in the answers I think a little more detail would help answer your question. Do you want to do a full drive to drive like copy like one would do on a PC with clonezilla (operating system level copy) or just your user data? If just user data look into a app called AirDroid. From what I notice in it you can copy user level data to a PC and back out again to another phone. I have yet to try this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few backup apps in the Google Play Store. I personally prefer [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=de). It lets you backup apps (APKs as well as app data) and call log, etc. to your internal or external storage (SD card) or to a computer. You can then restore your backup to another device.

There is, however, a thing to note:

Although Helium doesn't *require* root, you will (afaik) not be able to your restore app data without it. This is because app data is stored on a protected partition of your device's internal storage which you cannot write to without root access. But I haven't tried that yet, since I always root my devices.

Comment: This seems like an app backup/restore... What OP meant was a complete backup of the device to another.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way of doing this, as some of your data may not be readily available on your phone to be transferred to another device i.e computer. For example, the contacts on your phone needs to be exported first, before you can transfer it to another device.

If you have those data available for transfer, simply plug your device to a computer via USB cable, then use the Android File Transfer. Search for your files using your Computer's explorer to manually locate the files from your phone's storage, then copy and paste it to your computer.

Otherwise, the best method to transfer everything is by using a Cloud Storage.